# How can I update a field in a MySQL database table by addition in MySQL database in a single query

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores a value that will be added to over time. When I want to add to the value I would like to do so in a single query rather than -

1. Get oldValue from database
2. newValue = oldValue + X
3. update row with newValue

   $query1 = "SELECT value FROM table WHERE id = thisID";
   $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $oldValue = $row['value'];
   }
   $newValue = $oldValue + x
   $query1 = "UPDATE table SET value = $newValue WHERE id = thisID";

Can this be done in a single query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET value = value + x WHERE id = thisID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET field = oldValue + X WHERE id = 1
```