# How to add to an existing value in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update, insert-update

I'm back with another absolute beginner question, I have values stored in a database, my goal is to allow users to either subtract or add to a specific database value (quantity) using a drop down menu with values from ranging from 1 - 10. I'm keeping it simple for now.

```
mysql_select_db("toner", $con);
$sql=INSERT INTO inventory (partnumber, quantity)
VALUES
('$_POST[partnumber]','$_POST[quantity]');
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($con);
```

I can find plenty of examples just adding or deleting a static value however that's not what I need. I've searched around and few examples resembling what I'm looking for [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721127/how-can-i-update-a-field-in-a-mysql-database-table-by-addition-in-mysql-database) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536929/how-to-update-mysql-with-php-when-subtracting) It seems as though UPDATE would be the best solution however I'm not sure exactly how it should be implemented, I've also looking into concatenation but I'm not sure it can accomplish what I need, any assistance you can offer this novice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: UPDATE inventory SET quantity = 12 WHERE partnumber = 42 ...

Comment: I see in example 1 UPDATE table SET field = oldValue + X WHERE id = 1
However I'm not sure how to implement this or where the 1 comes into play? In your comment what does the 12 refer to? Basically this is a little too vague for me to understand.

Comment: The 12 was just a random number I pulled out of my head. It was to show how you could impliment a update

Comment: If you only have one item in the database this will update that one item. Assuming that the table is indexed by 'partnumber' (it is a unique number)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the following solution to work you will need to insert a value into the database for instance partnumber = 1 and qantity = 0. You will definatly need to modify this to work with your mysql connection string and will need to look in the database after to check that it has worked or add a select query. However this will update the inventory item 1's quantity with that selected in the dropdown...

file.php

```
<?php
    include("db_connection_file.php"); // in here are the username and password etc for your mysql connection
    if($_POST){ // the code in this block will ONLY fire if the form has been posted
        $dropdown_contents = $_POST['drop']; // this is the value of the form item 'drop' that has been posted...
        $part_no_from_form = $_POST['part_no'];
        $query ="UPDATE inventory SET quantity = '".$dropdown_contents."' WHERE partnumber = '".$part_no_from_form ."'"; // this updates the database and sets the quantity to that posted where the part number is that in the form
        $testResult = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 
        echo "This worked";
    }
?>
<form acion="file.php" method="post">
    Quantity <select name="drop" id="drop">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
    </select><br />
    Part No. <select name="part_no" id="part_no">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

Note: This can easily be extended to specify which partnumber you want to UPDATE in the database by adding say another dropdown or inputbox, catching the value posted and passing it through the where part of the Update query.

THIS HAS NO VALIDATION WHATSO EVER! It is also using depreciated MySQL connection functions, please look up MySQLi and PDO

Comment: No worries! If you need more help just ask here and I will do my best to help. the $dropdown_contents = $_POST['drop'];. So when the form is posted the $dropdown_contents is filled with the value of the form item called 'drop' which in this case is a select. I will comment the code a little more in a minute to help it make more sense. I am guessing that you are very very new to PHP then?

Comment: Ah - I'm a self study aswell. Trying to teach myself ASP.NET C# at the moment haha. *sigh*. Do you have a row in the database that has 'partnumber' with a value of '1'? It may pay to empty the database all but that one row just to get started - will make it easier to debug. Under this line: if($_POST){ ... you could put print_r($_POST); which will show you all the values that have been posted from the form and under $query ="UPDATE invento.. row you could put print_r($query); which would show you the contents of the query which would show you if the query is complete

Comment: Ah I miss read your question. My solution replaces the value of 'quantity' with the value from the dropdown, if the 'partnumber' is '1'. It will not add or subtract from it, just replace the value. It is pretty simple to add or subtract. Just need to decided if you want to add or subtract and add a little bit to the current update query as Matt Clark posted below. It will pay to make sure that the current query works as it is. If it echos 'This Worked' then the query didn't error. The query will not error if it does not find a record it can update it will only error if the query is malformed

Comment: No worries. Leme know if you get stuck

Comment: I'm attempting to work that in but I see your update gives me another drop down, I was attempting to use the same drop down with values 1 -10 and have another dropdown which displays each part, so I'm trying to stick with two drop downs only, but again I definitely appreciate you taking the time and effort to help me out!!!

Comment: You could do it without another dropdown if you specified the 'partnumber' in the query as before I updated the code. Before it was set to update where the 'partnumber' = 1, just change that to 2 for example? Does that make sense or have I missed what you meant?

Comment: That was it, all I had to do was add a + quantity in there, now I will add a subtract button and start expanding thanks again for the lesson!

Answer (score 0):

To update a row to a new KNOWN value:

```
UPDATE inventory SET quantity = $KnownValue WHERE partnumber = $PartNumber;
```

To update a row adding to an existing value, i.e. an additional 5 units were added to inventory:

```
UPDATE inventory SET quantity = quantity + $IncramentalValue WHERE partnumber = $PartNumber;
```

Comment: If you do not use partnumber, it will update every row in the table to the new quantity, say you have 500 items, it will change the quantity of all 500 items to the new set quantity. You need to tell it which item you will be updating the quantity for, and partnumber was the only row mentioned that would be used to distinguish between  parts.